# Does anyone know how to speed it up? More efficient way to derive a new graph from a given one

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks

Let us consider a `graph1`.

```
g1 = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 19,19 <-> 20, 19 <-> 22, 20 <-> 21, 20 <-> 23, 7 <-> 8, 8 <-> 24, 24 <-> 25, 24 <-> 26, 8 <-> 9, 9 <-> 10, 9 <-> 27, 27 <-> 28, 27 <-> 29, 10 <-> 11, 11 <-> 12, 12 <-> 13, 13 <-> 14, 14 <-> 15,15 <-> 16, 16 <-> 17, 17 <-> 18, 12 <-> 30, 30 <-> 31, 31 <-> 32, 32 <-> 33, 30 <-> 34, 31 <-> 35, 32 <-> 36, 34 <-> 37, 34 <-> 38, 2 <-> 39, 3 <-> 40, 4 <-> 41, 5 <-> 42, 6 <-> 43, 10 <-> 44, 11 <-> 45, 13 <-> 46, 14 <-> 47, 15 <-> 48, 16 <-> 49, 17 <-> 50,18 <-> 51, 18 <-> 52, 1 <-> 53, 1 <-> 54};
```

```
graph1 = Graph[g1, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", EdgeStyle -> Thick]
```

The color version of `graph1` looks like this:

[image: graph1]

Let us imagine that it is a network of streets. The red trail is the longest street. The longest street connects directly to 18 smaller streets — this is the degree of the middle vertex in `graph1`. The second longest street is dark blue – this street connects to three other streets, and so on. In this way we obtain `graph2`:

[image: graph2]

```
g2 = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 1 <-> 7, 1 <-> 8,1 <-> 9, 1 <-> 10, 1 <-> 11, 1 <-> 12, 9 <-> 13, 1 <-> 14, 1 <-> 15,1 <-> 16, 12 <-> 17, 1 <-> 18, 12 <-> 19, 12 <-> 20, 1 <-> 21,1 <-> 22, 1 <-> 23, 8 <-> 24, 4 <-> 25, 4 <-> 26, 20 <-> 27};
```

```
graph2 = Graph[g2, GraphLayout -> "RadialDrawing"]
```

I wrote a script which calculates `graph2` based on `graph1`, but it is very slow. I need a simple script for calculating large networks.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you share what you've done?

Comment: I will wait for some response. My code is relatively long.

Comment: How did you get the coloring of your `graph1`?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "longest street" and "second longest street". Can you define these precisely?  For example, it is not at all clear to me what the expected result is for `{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 
 8 <-> 1, 4 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, 2 <-> 10, 10 <-> 6}`

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not confused by the term "street" (I don't think it should have been edited out). My point was that these concepts are unclear if there are loops in the graph. If you only work with trees, it is important to say so.

Comment: @Szabolcs for a previous version of this, provided an answer that works. Pretty sure there is not always a unique g2.

Comment: @b3m2a1 The difficulty is not that there isn't a unique solution. It is that the problem is not well defined. What does "longest street" even mean?  Longest shortest path?  Longest possible path without repeating edges?  Without repeating vertices?  This makes a big difference (also in how difficult/slow the computation would be).

Comment: @Szabolcs maybe the better explanation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139896/38205) might help

Comment: How to speed *what* up?  Also, the question is still unclear. Who haven't addressed any of the comments asking to clarify.

Comment: i.e. speed up 'Carl Woll' code listed below

Comment: How is this different from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139896/recreating-a-hierarchical-graph-from-a-compact-representation)?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can transform the graph by finding the longest path, vertex contracting the path, and then repeat starting with the new contracted vertex neighbors. Here is some code to do this:

```
longestPath[g_, s_:Automatic] := Module[{p = GraphPeriphery[g], ends},
    ends = If[s===Automatic, Subsets[p, {2}], Thread[{s, p}]];
    ends = First @ MaximalBy[ends, GraphDistance[g, Sequence@@#]&, 1];
    First @ FindPath[g,Sequence@@ends]
]

refactor[g_, s_:Automatic] := Module[{long, new, adj},
    If[VertexCount[g]<2, Return[]];
    long = Sow @ longestPath[g,s];
    new = VertexContract[g, long];
    adj = AdjacencyList[new, First@long];
    new = VertexDelete[new, First@long];
    Map[
        refactor[Subgraph[new, First @ ConnectedComponents[new, #]], #]&,
        adj
    ]
]

contractions[g_] := First @ Last @ Reap @ refactor[g]

transform[g_] := Graph[
    Fold[VertexContract, g, contractions[g]],
    GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"
]
```

For your example:

```
transform[Graph @ g1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But there is a problem - errors appear - example: graph data is here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gXz0gxGekmfH1DJZ53Ox17svfkRnkl9L?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the problem is with 'p = GraphPeriphery[g]'. It should be 'p = GraphPeriphery[g, Method -> "PseudoDiameter"]'.  But the code is still slow. Can you enter some counter (at which stage of calculation is the code)?

Comment: Does anyone know how to speed it up?